# flask: Intermittent sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError on apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, pyodbc

I have been getting an error intermittently with my flask app which requires me to restart the Apache service to fix. Any suggestions on what the problem could be is much appreciated.

**My environment:**

- apache with mod_wsgi
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- python 3.6
- flask with flask-sqlalchemy
- pyodbc connecting to SQL Server 2012

**The exact error in the Apache logs:**

```
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.497453 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] mod_wsgi (pid=8760): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'E:/webapps/license-monitor-tool/wsgi.py'., referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.555451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     context)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\default.py", line 470, in do_execute\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\\r\\n (10054) (SQLExecDirectW)')\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] \r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] \r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1997, in __call__\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     response = self.handle_exception(e)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     raise value\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     raise value\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     rv = self.dispatch_request()\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.556451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\flaskapp.py", line 87, in dashboard\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     servers = db.session.query(Server).all()\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\orm\\query.py", line 2703, in all\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     return list(self)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\orm\\query.py", line 2855, in __iter__\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     return self._execute_and_instances(context)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\orm\\query.py", line 2878, in _execute_and_instances\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\base.py", line 945, in execute\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     return meth(self, multiparams, params)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\sql\\elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     compiled_sql, distilled_params\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     context)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     exc_info\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\util\\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\util\\compat.py", line 186, in reraise\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     raise value.with_traceback(tb)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     context)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]   File "E:\\webapps\\license-monitor-tool\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\engine\\default.py", line 470, in do_execute\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030]     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
[Fri Sep 29 10:04:39.557448 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 8760:tid 1084] [client 10.242.186.222:65030] sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\\r\\n (10054) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'SELECT flexlm_server.id AS flexlm_server_id, flexlm_server.name AS flexlm_server_name, flexlm_server.port AS flexlm_server_port \\nFROM flexlm_server']\r, referer: http://devinfosandbox/license-monitor-tool/products
```

## My Code

**wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
venv = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'venv', 'Scripts', 'activate_this.py')
with open(venv) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=venv))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)
from flaskapp import app as application
```

**flaskapp.py** (snippet)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.teardown_request
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db.session.remove()

@app.route('/products')
def products():
    servers_query = db.session.query(Server).all()
    server = request.args.get('server')
    core_products = db.session.execute("flexlm_products_by_server :p1,:p2", {'p1': 'core', 'p2': server}).fetchall()
    ext_products = db.session.execute("flexlm_products_by_server :p1,:p2", {'p1': 'extension', 'p2': server}).fetchall()
    return render_template('pages/placeholder.products.html',
                           servers=servers_query,
                           core=core_products,
                           ext=ext_products)
```

**models.py** (snippet)

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskapp import db

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'flexlm_product'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('server_id', 'internal_name', name='UQ_server_internalname'),
        db.UniqueConstraint('server_id', 'common_name', name='UQ_server_commonname'),
    )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    server_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("flexlm_server.id"), nullable=False)
    internal_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    common_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    license_out = db.Column(db.Integer)
    license_total = db.Column(db.Integer)
    FlexLM_server = db.relationship(u'Server')

    def __init__(self, server_id, internal_name, **kwargs):
        self.server_id = server_id
        self.internal_name = internal_name
        super(Product, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Howdy! As you've probably noticed, this error bubbles up from SQL Server itself: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187005(v=sql.105).aspx What version of `pyodbc` are you using? It looks like the issue may be the version of the SQL Server Native Client you are using, according to the link provided.

Comment: @FlipperPA the `pyodbc` version is `4.0.17`. My connection string is using `driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0`. According to [this link](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows) I am using the correct driver. I suppose i could try `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` to see if that works better.

Comment: Do you have a NAT between your app server and your database?

Comment: @univerio not sure. Our network is fairly complex and I am not involved with that team. Is there any easy way to check this?

Comment: Is your code trying to cache the database session connection at global scope and reuse it. If so, your code has to be tolerant of the connection being dropped and create a new session. Try creating a new session connection for each request instead, if you were trying to cache it and reuse the connection across requests.